# QTConcurrent doesn't compile

Tags: c++, qt, qtconcurrent

I have a recursive directory copy function I'd like to run in the background. The function takes two QString arguments, filepath and dir.

From .pro:

```
QT += core gui sql network concurrent
greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets
LIBS += -lQt5Concurrent
```

From code:

```
#include <QtConcurrent/QtConcurrent>
#include <qtconcurrentrun.h>
#include <QThread>
...

QFuture <void> future = QtConcurrent::run(copyFolder(filepath,dir));
```

I get the following compile error:

```
 error: no matching function for call to 'run'
 QFuture <void> future = QtConcurrent::run(copyFolder(filepath,dir) );
                  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

If I call the function like this:

```
QFuture <void> future = QtConcurrent::run(copyFolder, filepath,dir );

error: reference to non-static member function must be called
QFuture <void> future = QtConcurrent::run(copyFolder, filepath,dir );
                            ^~~~~~~~~~
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are there any other lines below the error? E.g. "note: candidates are:" and so on?

Comment: Yes. Quite a few.

Comment: After the edit, You seem to be trying to call another member function using `QtConcurrent::run`, see my answer.

Comment: The `LIBS += -lQt5Concurrent` is wrong. The relevant libraries are automatically linked with when you provide `QT += concurrent`. You also don't need the `core` module. And since your code likely doesn't support Qt 4 anyway, you can get rid of the `greaterThan` test. Then the four lines of the `.pro` file that you show above reduce to `QT += widgets concurrent network sql`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I get the following compile error:
>
> ```
> error: no matching function for call to 'run'
> QFuture <void> future = QtConcurrent::run(copyFolder(filepath,dir) );
>                   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
> ```

You shouldn't be passing arguments the way you are doing. Instead you should pass your function's argument as arguments to `QtConcurrent::run`, see docs [here](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtconcurrentrun.html#passing-arguments-to-the-function).

Your call should look something like this:

```
QFuture <void> future = QtConcurrent::run(copyFolder, filepath, dir);
```

This way `QtConcurrent` will copy the arguments you have passed and perform the function call in a thread from the default `QThreadPool` .

> If I call the function like this:
>
> ```
> QFuture <void> future = QtConcurrent::run(copyFolder, filepath,dir );
>   error: reference to non-static member function must be called
> QFuture <void> future = QtConcurrent::run(copyFolder, filepath,dir );
>                                ^~~~~~~~~~
> ```

If you have to call a non-static member function in your class, you have to pass the object that you want to run the function on, see docs [here](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtconcurrentrun.html#using-member-functions). Assuming you are using `QtConcurrent::run` from another member function in your class (since you would get a different error if not), you should do something like this:

```
QFuture <void> future = QtConcurrent::run(this, &ClassName::copyFolder, filepath, dir);
```

**Note that**, you have to make sure that that all accesses to shared data (between both threads) should be serialized (maybe using a `QMutex`).

Comment: I edited the question. I get a different error using this technique.